# How to completly remove a field?

Tags: entities

I have removed a field from a bundle (it is not used somewhere else) by using the graphical UI.

But it is still listed when I run the following command (after cache clear)

```
$this->entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $bundle);
```

What should I do to completely remove it (as I use the previous command to display some list)

**edit to add**:

Following the proposal of Clive, I ran the `field_cron()` without success. Looking at the code of this function, I tried the following code to have more information:

```
$deleted_fields_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_field.deleted_fields_repository');
$fields = $deleted_fields_repository->getFieldDefinitions(NULL);
```

As you can imagine, `$fields` is empty. Maybe some kind of corruption?

**edit to add 2**

Following the proposal of 4k4 I ran this code:

```
$field_storage = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', 'the_field_that_must_be_deleted');
dpm($field_storage->get('persist_with_no_fields'));
```

And the result is `FALSE`

Thus the question is: how to manually remove a field?

Comment: Could be the field storage is marked as persist_with_no_fields, which means it should persist even if no longer used in any bundle.

Comment: @4k4: I have updated my question: looks like it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just run cron for this, because [`field_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_cron/9.3.x) clears the deleted data.

If you need to do it manually for whatever reason, you can call [`field_purge_batch()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.purge.inc/function/field_purge_batch/9.3.x) manually.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it is a correct answer but not useful in my case. I have updated my question.